# Select doubles using nth-child() in CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Say I have the following structure for a list:

```
<ul>
    <li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li>
</ul>
```

and each `<li>` is 50% width so I want every two to have the same background colour like this:

```
<ul>
    <li style="background:#CCC;"></li><li style="background:#CCC;"></li>
    <li style="background:#DDD;"></li><li style="background:#DDD;"></li>
    <li style="background:#CCC;"></li><li style="background:#CCC;"></li>
    <li style="background:#DDD;"></li><li style="background:#DDD;"></li>
</ul>
```

Can I do this using the 'nth-child()' CSS selector so as to **minimise code**?

Comment: Why not use a table as it seems like that is what your are making the list act like anyway?

Comment: They're not actually 50% but set widths, was just to set the scene. Tables are ugly, I prefer table-less design.

Comment: Yet your list will look like a table when you have alternating colors, just seems to contradict your table-less design when your implementation will make it look like a table anyway.

Comment: Instead of using the nth-child, can you give each li a class(one for one color, one for the other) then you can just set to background color of the class in css and get your result.

Comment: But if I have site wide css set for all ul and li elements already then it makes sense to continue using them rather than create a whole new set of css and worry about cell borders, padding, margins etc.

Comment: Yes but the point is to minimise code! Why waste bandwidth creating pointless classes when the `nth-child()` could potentially do the same, my question is about the `nth-child()` because I don't know if it can do it or not, I know how to do it otherways or even with 1px backgrounds repeated horizontally for the ul.

Comment: @jzworkman: It looks like a table, but is it a table? No. That's what Silver89 is driving at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ul li:nth-child(4n+1),
ul li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: #CCC;
}
ul li:nth-child(4n+3),
ul li:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: #DDD;
}
```

This will give you every 4th element starting with the 1st, and 2nd as color #CCC and every 4th element starting with the 3rd and 4th as #DDD

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mU2tn/1/

Comment: Perfect! Can just set the default li as one colour then change just the 3rd and 4th so even less css :)

Comment: @BoltClock The OP said he already had that in his css(which he didnt provide) so I didnt bother adding it all in, I was just showing how to do the coloring.

Answer (score 2):

```
li{
   /* All LIs*/
}
li:nth-child(4n+1),
li:nth-child(4n+2) {
   /* Li 1, 2,
         5, 6,
         9, 10 */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it with only CSS(3). Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fnwhD/)**.

```
li {
    width:100%;
}
li:nth-child(4n) {
    background:#999;
}
li:nth-child(4n-1) {
    background:#999;
}
li:nth-child(4n-2) {
    background:#ccc;
}
li:nth-child(4n-3) {
    background:#ccc;
}
```

​

Answer (score 2):

I believe this CSS should get what you aim to do.

```
ul li:nth-child(4n+1), ul li:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background: #ccc;
}

ul li:nth-child(4n+3), ul li:nth-child(4n){
    background: #ddd;
}
```

This JSFiddle shows it in action.
http://jsfiddle.net/u2W84/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps all the other answers work, but this is what I'd do:

```
ul li {
    background: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd), 
ul li:nth-child(odd) + li {
    background: green;
}
```

Edit: no sorry, that didn't work :P Gimme a sec.

Comment: This basically works identically to `ul li:nth-child(odd), ul li:nth-child(even)`, which selects all of them and overrides `ul li` completely.

Comment: You're correct, didn't realize at first that `:nth-child(odd) + li` affects _all_ `li` elements after an odd one, not just the first.

Comment: Or rather, it affects the `li` element after *all odd ones*. The selector that takes all elements that come after another is `~`.

Comment: Thank's to whoever upvoted but TBH this was far from correct :P