# CSS Every other LI element but in pairs of two

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a CSS issue in which I need to select every other PAIR of elements and change the background-color accordingly. **I CANNOT** add additional classes to the pairs, I have been trying to use a combinations of `:nth-child` in order to find a solution. Wondering if anyone has done this before and can point me in the right direction

```
ul li:nth-child(2n + 1) { background-color: blue; }
ul li:nth-child(2n + 0) { background-color: blue; }
ul li:nth-child(3n + 0) { background-color: green; }
ul li:nth-child(4n + 0) { background-color: green; }

  <ul>
    <li>Item 1 Group 1</li>
    <li>Item 2 Group 1</li>

    <li>Item 1 Group 2</li><!-- Make BG Blue -->
    <li>Item 2 Group 2</li><!-- Make BG Blue -->

    <li>Item 1 Group 3</li>
    <li>Item 2 Group 3</li>

    <li>Item 1 Group 4</li><!-- Make BG Blue -->
    <li>Item 2 Group 4</li><!-- Make BG Blue -->

    <li>Item 1 Group 5</li>
    <li>Item 2 Group 5</li>
  </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qpDUf/

Comment: This has been asked several times in the past year but for some strange reason I can't locate any of this year's duplicates. I did, however, find some of the earliest occurrences that I remember... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912601/select-doubles-using-nth-child-in-css3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375293/nth-child-for-every-two-table-rows

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
li:nth-child(4n + 1), li:nth-child(4n + 2) {
    background-color: green;
}
li:nth-child(4n + 3), li:nth-child(4n + 4) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```css
li:nth-child(4n + 1), li:nth-child(4n + 2) {
    background-color: green;
}
li:nth-child(4n + 3), li:nth-child(4n + 4) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1 Group 1</li>
    <li>Item 2 Group 1</li>

    <li>Item 1 Group 2</li><!-- Make BG Blue -->
    <li>Item 2 Group 2</li><!-- Make BG Blue -->

    <li>Item 1 Group 3</li>
    <li>Item 2 Group 3</li>

    <li>Item 1 Group 4</li><!-- Make BG Blue -->
    <li>Item 2 Group 4</li><!-- Make BG Blue -->

    <li>Item 1 Group 5</li>
    <li>Item 2 Group 5</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting the group size like: nth-child([size]n+[position])

```
ul li:nth-child(4n + 1) { background-color: blue; }
ul li:nth-child(4n + 2) { background-color: blue; }
ul li:nth-child(4n + 3) { background-color: green; }
ul li:nth-child(4n + 4) { background-color: green; }
```

I updated your jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/qpDUf/1/

Is that the sort of thing you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This selector is simplest:

```
ul li:nth-child(4n),
ul li:nth-child(4n + 3)
{ background-color: blue; }
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/qpDUf/5/

Answer (score 0):

I've succesfully used this hack:

Firstly: set global color for `<li>`

```
li { background-color: blue; }
```

Secondly: select every 4th element and apply alternative background to `<li>` element directly after it. That makes pairs. -1 to begin from the right place.

```
li:nth-child(4n-1) { background-color: green; }
li:nth-child(4n-1)+li { background-color: green; }
```

Enjoy!